# Is there a way to get notified on new questions on specific topics/tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, notifications

I mean that if I think I am "master" in some topic or tag (iOS address book, localization etc.), I wish to get an alert when a user posted a question tagged with a specific tag. Is there a way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do that by *subscribing* to the tags you are interested in, thus getting email alerts – you can subscribe from the tag mouseover.

[image: tag mouseover]

However, if you're familiar with RSS, I recommend to use the builtin RSS feeds, since you can do that not only for single tags, but also for some boolean combinations of them: see this [blog.SO post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/).

Comment: To find all tags, go to this page. https://stackoverflow.com/tags

Answer (score 8):

Another way is to feed the topics to a Slack channel.

Suppose you create a new team in [Slack](https://slack.com/get-started) and a new channel, called `Linux`.

After you log in to the Slack team, go to one channel and run the below command to add a new topic, `linux`, in it.

```
/feed subscribe http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=linux&sort=newest
```

Then you will keep getting new questions about Linux from Stack Overflow.

You are fine to add any topics which you are interesting in with the below format: `http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=<TOPIC>&sort=newest`

Run `/feed help` to get help.

The good part with Slack is, I normally create a channel called `linux-tech-questions`. I collect all Linux questions I am interested from different sources, not only from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why do this on slack when you can already do it on http://stackexchange.com/filters? :)

Comment: will you get notification from StackExchange? Emails easily get ignored if you get several hundred emails daily. Secondly, it is my habit to deal with technical questions. So I can send the feeds from different sources to different slack channels.

Comment: I feel like stackexchange.com/filters is underappreciated and like to plug it whenever I can. :D The filter notification mails are sent from do-not-reply@stackexchange.com. What I usually do for sorting, is use [tagged email addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Sub-addressing) (e.g. the "xyz" in "myself+xyz@gmail.com") and then I use that as criteria for sorting / labeling. The other thing I find convenient is just an RSS reader browser extension, if I want real-time notifications (the browser extensions are nice because they're always visible no matter what site you're on).

Comment: Yes, I know your meaning. But in these days, I don't check email frequently. If my friend need contact me, there are a lot of instant way to do, but not email. Email for me is out-of-day style. Same reason for RSS, it is too old, no fun.